# Placebo Neural Network that can back-propagate but will give no improvement

Tags: pytorch, mnist

What would be an easy way to create a useless neural network for testing, that can back-propagate (so that there is no need to comment out `loss.backward()`) and is trainable, but it would not give any improvement to prediction accuracy?

E.g. Below is a neural network for the MNIST dataset. How should I create a counterpart that would also give output of the same dimension (batch_size * 10), that would enable the `loss` tensor to back-propagate gradients, but would give no improvement in accuracy?

```
class test_net_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test_net_1,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,1,kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(26*26,10)
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = x.view(-1,26*26)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x)
        return x
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to modify. Something needs to be modified to ensure no learning can occur. For example you could back-propagate loss with random target classes. Or, you replace gradients with a gradient orthogonal, or approximately orthogonal to your actual gradient. Or you could just zero the gradients after back-propagation. Or you could simply detach the output from the computation graph before returning from forward. Its not clear which of these would be acceptable based on the description provided.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to be able to call `loss.backward()` without updating the weights of your model while calling `step()`. This can be achieved by freezing al the modules of your model with:

```py
class test_net_1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test_net_1,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,1,kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(26*26,10)
        self.conv1.requires_grad = False  # Note this line.
        self.fc1.requires_grad = False  # Note this line.

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = x.view(-1,26*26)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.log_softmax(x)
        return x
```

Comment: I tried your mentioned method of adding the line ```self.requires_grad = False```. However, the network is still being trained.